# URL leading directly to comment on blog article

Tags: url, comments, blogger, blogs

Is there a way to construct a URL that will lead directly to the comment left by someone on a blog article?

For exammple, is there a way to construct a URL that will lead directly to the comment left by Alexander in the following blog article?

http://zeroseconde.blogspot.com/2008/09/fin-du-papier.html

Similarly, is there a way to construct a URL that will lead directly to the comment left by jokeefe on the following blog article?

https://www.metafilter.com/74067/The-Image-Mill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this? -> http://zeroseconde.blogspot.com/2008/09/fin-du-papier.html?showComment=1223573700000#c4070187594579786156

If so, simply right click on the comment date and copy the url.

The same works to get the URL for jokeefe's comment in the second question.